# Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. in angular 7

Tags: angular

Error:

```
BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy-loaded module, import `CommonModule` instead.
```

After upgrade from `Angular` 5 to 7, I got this error. please help me out of this issue

Comment: you might have imported `BrowserModule` in multiple modules, only import it in `app.module.ts`

Comment: can you share your app.module.ts

Comment: If you are using any custom angular packages (made by you), make sure they have only CommonModule instead of BrowserModule.

Answer (score 1):

> Import below **`modules`** only once in the **`root module (app.module.ts)`**:

```
BrowserModule 
BrowserAnimationsModule 
HttpModule
HttpClientModule
```

Answer (score 0):

**Fixed By Myself**

Global and Local project ng version entirly different.After uninstall global ng version ,the problem was solved.During conflict time i having more than one webpack list .after remove that webpack it working fine